# Ansible until loop with regex in conditional statement

Tags: regex, ansible, until-loop

I need to check command stdout with a regex pattern in until loop. When I using regex_search to display debug msg all works fine:

```
    - name: Checking if node is ready
      shell: "kubectl --kubeconfig {{kubeconf}} get nodes"
      register: k_output

    - debug:
        msg: "{{k_output.stdout | regex_search(node_hostname | string + '\\s+Ready')}}"
```

The message is

```
ok: [any_node_hostname] => {
    "msg": "any_node_hostname   Ready"
}
```

But if I trying to use that construction inside until conditional statement task fails with syntax error.

```
    - set_fact:
        regexp_pattern: "{{node_hostname | string + '\\s+Ready'}}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{regexp_pattern}}"

    - name: Checking if node is ready
      shell: "kubectl --kubeconfig {{kubeconf}} get nodes"
      register: k_output
      until: "{{k_output.stdout | regex_search(regexp_pattern)}}" != ""
      retries: 5
      delay: 10
```

The same behaviour without set_fact when I just copying and pasting full string `{{k_output.stdout | regex_search(node_hostname | string + '\\s+Ready')}}` to until conditional statement.
So, how can I use regex_search or something that fits this case with until?

Answer (score 2):

you have syntax error at `until:` statement : you must not quote the vars in expression, like in example here : [Retrying a task until a condition is met](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html?highlight=until#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met)

```
    until: k_output.stdout | regex_search(regexp_pattern) != ""
```

I hope this will help